# Power BI : Mystery Icon

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, calculated-columns

I have to fix an old PowerBI report that I didn't create.

My problem is the "BU" variable which is a column but it is NOT a variable which come from the origin table "COMMON - Accounts". It looks like a calculated column and it never appear in every table in power query.
Moreover, I don't know the logo to the left of the "BU" variable. Has anyone seen this logo ?

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a group column.

[image]

You can learn more about binning here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-grouping-and-binning

You can also see a full list and meaning of icons here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-field-list

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks a lot !